# Where is the "CSS preview" and "CSS Style Builder" in Netbeans?

Tags: css, netbeans, ide

Just a little question. I'm following the Affable Bean tutorial from netbeans page.

The tutorial says that we can use a "**CSS preview**" and a "**CSS Style builder**" windows:

[image]

Located in "Window > Other", but I can't find them, my IDE looks like this:

[image]

Where can I find these windows? I'm using Netbeans 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closing as **stylebuilder** has been **removed** from the netbeans and there's the new css stying tools also working in embedded css code.

which is >> WINDOW >> WEB >> CSS STYLES

Comment: So.. does netbeans not include a CSS preview? Do I need to deploy de app and see in the browser?